# Incorrect Section numbering while compiling multiples LaTeX files

Tags: sectioning, pdftex, texlive

I am trying to compile multiple LaTeX files that are basically individual lecture notes into a Grand Report. I am using a `main.tex` file that compiles all individual TeX files along with a separate `preamble.tex`. I have attached the `main.tex`, `preamble.tex`, and `lec1_MM.tex` file snippets at the end of the question.

[image: 1]Picture of the Final pdf where section numbers are incorrect]

The whole thing works well and I get a decent output pdf but **all section numbers are shifted that is, sections are shown as subsections and subsections as subsubsections**. All parts where I have used `\section` appears as a subsection in my `main.pdf`. I could not figure out where the error was but mostly think that modifying the `main.tex` might help.

I will be grateful if anyone could point out where this unforeseen error is and how I can overcome this. Thank you in advance!

The following is my `main.tex` file:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\input{./preamble.tex}

\title{Course-code \\ Course-name \\ Lecture Notes}
\author{Author}
\date{September '20 - December '20}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents

\input{../lec1/lec1_MM.tex}
\input{../lec3/lec3_MM.tex}

\end{document}
```

And this is my first tex file ie `lec1_MM.tex`. I am just putting the initial part of the file for brevity.

```latex
% \begin{document}
\smallskip
\centerline{\date{September 22, 2020}}

\section{About the course}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Instructor - Prof X (\href{url}{webpage})
    \item Class Timings
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Monday 5pm
            \item Thursday 5pm
            \item Friday 10am $\Rightarrow $ Online Discussion
            \item Grading -- TBA
```

This is the preamble.tex file. Since I was trying it for the first time, it is quiet simple.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but do you think it could be because you put the 'section' command inside the input file? I usually put the section and subsection commands in the main file and then call the input or source file after that.

Comment: Report class has the `\chapter` and not the `\section` as "top level" sectioning command ... It is closer to a book than to an article

Comment: @Plergux, I dont think so. Sometimes I have more than one section within a subfile and it won't be possible to call a section or subsection everytime in the main.tex file.

Comment: @koleygr Haha! It worked! I just had to change report to article. 
That indeed was a simple solution! Thanks a lot, mate! :)

Comment: Welcome @Ananth_Rao ... Happy TeXing!